# CanExecute Not working CommunityToolkit.Mvvm -Version 8.0.0-preview4

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, community-toolkit-mvvm

Why the CanExecute property for RelayCommandAttribute Not working in CommunityToolkit.Mvvm -Version 8.0.0-preview4

ex :
this will work

```
public bool CanDo(string x) => true;
[RelayCommand(CanExecute=nameof(CanDo))]]
public void DoSomthing(string x){}
```

but this not :

```
public bool CanDo(string? x) => true;

[RelayCommand(CanExecute=nameof(CanDo))]
public void DoSomthing(string? x){}
```

it show this Error
error MVVMTK0011: The CanExecute name must refer to a compatible member, but no valid members were found for "CanDo" in type  ...